# PHP call function with default arguments

Tags: php, function, arguments, default

in many languages I can do something like this:

```
function f(a = 0, b = 0, c = 0)
{
   // Do something
}

f(b=3, c=4);
```

Can I do something like this in PHP?

Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: Did you give it a try?

Comment: [check here](https://eval.in/124773)

Comment: The simple answer is "No", PHP doesn't support named arguments when calling a function

Comment: @Shankar Probably because it's not. There's no syntax for named parameters like in the example, and no keyword for skipping positional parameters.

Comment: @IMSoP,  `func_get_args` can be of help indirectly right ?

Comment: @Shankar I can't think of any way that would help. You've still just got an ordered list of arguments and no way of skipping one, which is what I assumed the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately you can't "step over" arguments in PHP, so default values are only possible at the end of the list.

So you can write this:

```
 function foo($a=0, $b=0) {}
 foo(42);
```

Here `$b` will have its default value but `$a` won't, as we provided one value as input.

However there's no way of providing a value for `$b` without also providing one for `$a` - we have to provide the value for `$b` as the second parameter, and PHP has no keyword we can use in place of the first parameter to say "use default".

There is talk of adding named parameters to a future version of PHP, similar to your non-PHP example.

You can simulate this a bit with some changes to your code, though; a couple of ideas:

- treat `null` as meaning "use default", and write `$a = is_null($a) ? 42 : $a`
- make your functions take an associative array as their only parameter, and take values from it as though their keys were parameter names

Answer (score 0):

Indeed.

```
function foo($bar = "test") {
    echo "I want ".$bar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP this is not possible: see the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/functions.arguments.php). Function parameters are always evaluated from left to right.

However,

```
f($b=3, $c=4);
```

is possible, but does something different as you will expect: before the function f() is called, the arguments are evaluated (variable $b and $c get assigned with the values 3 and 4 resp.) and then the function is called as

```
f(3,4)
```

As side effect, the variables $b and $c are set to the new values.